# When http doesn't return answer I get UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, django

I have a website and I was trying to add a feature so that when you look for a movie title that doesn't exist, you get a message that says "Not results found". However, when I try the feature that I added with the else statement, I get this error: "UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'movie_data' referenced before assignment". It only happens when I search for something that doesn't exist. Why is it happening?

This is my view:

```
def index(request):
movies = []

if request.method == 'POST':
    
    film_url = 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/'
    
    search_params = {
        'films' : 'title',
        'films' : 'description',
        'films' : 'director',
        'films' : 'release_date',
        'q' : request.POST['search']
        
        }

    
    r = requests.get(film_url, params=search_params)
    results = r.json()
    

    for result in results:
         movie_data = {
            'Title' : result['title'],
            'Release_date': result['release_date'],
            'Director' : result['director'],
            'Producer' : result['producer'],
            'Description' : result['description']

        }

    movies.append(movie_data)  
    
 
else:
    message = 'Not results found'

context = {
'movies' : movies
}
    

return render(request,'core/index.html', context)
```

Comment: You forgot to indent the line `movies.append(movie_data)`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to test for results, and indented so that the result does not get appended:

```
if len(results):
    for result in results:
        
        movie_data = {
            'Title' : result['title'],
            'Release_date': result['release_date'],
            'Director' : result['director'],
            'Producer' : result['producer'],
            'Description' : result['description']
    
        }

        movies.append(movie_data)

else:
    message = 'Not results found'
```

Also, you're not sending `message` to the template.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that **You are using a variable which you haven't declared!**

The variable `movie_data` is declared inside the scope of the forloop. Thus, it is not accessible from outside.

You should move the line containing `movies.append(movie_data)` into the forloop statement.